# What are the advantages to using bitwise operations over boolean operations in Python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, low-level, high-level

I'm having trouble understanding just why I would want to use bitwise operators in a high-level language like Python. From what I have learned of high- vs low-level languages is that high-level ones are typically designed to that you don't have to worry too much about the machine code going into a computer.  I don't see the point of manipulating a program bit-by-bit in a language that, to my knowledge, was designed to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a concrete example of bitwise operators being used in the standard library, just look at the `re` library.  [According to the API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile), the flags are supposed to be bitwise `OR`ed together.

This allows you to pass a large number of options in a single argument.  Consider the following options:

```
re.compile(expression,re.I | re.M | re.X)
```

vs.

```
re.compile(expression,ignorecase=True,multiline=True,verbose=True)
```

I think we can agree that the first version is a lot more compact at least.

---

You may be thinking "Well, I like the second better -- after all, it is more explicit!" ... And you might have a case for that.  But what if you had a colleague who generated a binary file in C and he told you that the header of the file contained a 32 bit integer field and that integer field stores the flags necessary to decode the rest of the file?  You, being a reasonable person want to work with the file in a high-level language where you can manipulate the data easily and efficient so you choose python.  Now I bet you're glad you can do bitwise operations as to keep yourself from needing to use C to decode/analyze your file.

Comment: I never really thought about using them to work with other languages. That makes a  lot of sense. Thanks a lot. I guess I'll pay more attention to the classes on bitwise ops that are coming up next week.

Comment: @b4ux1t3 -- Also, FWIW, in python, operators map to function calls on the objects that they operate on.  So, the bitwise operators (`|&^`) can be overloaded to do cool things on other types as well.  For example, builtin set objects use `|` to mean union and `&` to mean intersection.

Answer (score 4):

There's definitely a use for bitwise operations in Python. Aside from `or`-ing flags, like mgilson mentions, I used them myself for composing packet headers for CAN messages. Very often, the headers for a lower-level message protocol are composed of fields that have a length that is not a multiple of 8 bits, so you would need bitwise operators if you want to change one field only.

Python being a higher-level language does not mean you cannot do low-level stuff with it!

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything using transmission protocols will end up using bitwise operation at some point - a set of flags that are all true or false will normally be combined into a single byte for up to 8 flags to save on bandwidth and short of having a dictionary of 255 values to decode it - don't laugh I have seen it done in more than one language in one case with very large number of if else statments - when at most a few bitwise operations were all that was needed.